# Interpolating within a boundary using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I am interpolating species density in a tidal flat however I would like to limit my interpolation to the sampled area in the tidal flat.

I tried making a shapefile of the sampled tidal flat area (barrier) and in Toolbox -> Thin plate spline -> output extent set to the polygon.

This did not produce the result I am looking for.
What is the correct process to limit the interpolation to my sampled area boundary?
I only have access to QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you're first attempt probably produced the species distribution in a rectangular area that covers the *extent* of the tidal flat. Now you can clip out of that rectangular interpolation just the tidal area with the cipper tool: "Raster -> Extraction -> Clipper" and in the window choose "Mask Layer" and select the tidal flat polygon to clip to the actual boundary.